# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when saving running save file macro

Tags: vba

When I run the macro I get the run time error and upon debugging it highlights the following code:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template Summary Screen").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(2)
```

What do you think is going on?

```
Sub saveasxlsx()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim staticFolder As String
Dim dateformat As String
Dim wbfirst As Workbook

Set wbfirst = ThisWorkbook

  wbfirst.RefreshAll

    'location of the parent folder
    staticFolder = "\\C:\Location\"

    'provides previous month YYYYMM
    dateformat = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Date), "yyyymm", 1)

   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template Summary Screen").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(2)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IPV").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(3)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADJ").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(4)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(5)

   'save the new workbook in the folder
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs staticFolder & "\" & dateformat & "\" & "Working files" & "\" & "GM AFS PE - UPLOAD VERSION" & " - " & dateformat & ".xlsx"

    'close the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Either "Template Summary Screen" does not exist in ThisWorkbook or Sheets(2) does not exist in wb. Splitting the statement into two, by first obtaining a reference to wb.Sheets(2), will tell you which is the problem.

Comment: (I bet it is "Template Summary Sheet" !) ;)

Comment: Got it to work! For some reason my excel had defaulted to a single sheet for new workbooks - just changed that and it works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

`Set wb = Workbooks.Add`

This creates a new Workbook with *one* sheet, so `wb.Sheets(1)` is the only valid sheet, any other integer is out of range.

To add the sheets you need use `wb.Sheets.Add()`

Comment: I would mention that the default for a new workbook is to contain 3 sheets, but this can be changed in the Excel options.

Comment: `Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)` will create a workbook with one sheet.  Just `Add` will use the default that you've set in the options (as @AndyG said the default default is 3).

Comment: Its one sheet by default in Excel 2016

Comment: Got it to work! For some reason my excel had defaulted to a single sheet for new workbooks - just changed that.

Comment: One is the default, if others are going to use your code you should explicitly create a book with one sheet then add however many you need to avoid having to worry about different defaults.

Comment: As the workbook is new anyway, you could use Before with `Sheets(1)` or After with `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` if you want it at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! For some reason my excel had defaulted to a single sheet for new workbooks - just changed that to 3 and it works fine